# pgAdmin 4 v4 does not prompt to save on page refresh

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

(I can't seem to find this issue anywhere else despite being a seemingly common issue)

Typically when I'm using the Query Editor I press F5 to run my query. With pgAdmin being a browser application, this can be an issue since F5 also refreshes web pages. In pgAdmin 4 v3, it would prompt to save my file if it tried to refresh the page, so it wasn't a big deal. It doesn't do that in version 4, so I have to save frequently and, when I forget, I just lose my progress with no warning.

How come pgAdmin 4 doesn't prompt to save? Is there a way to turn this back on? Is there a way I can reach out to the developers and request this be a feature, if it isn't already?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is a big issue too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version pgAdmin 4 v4.2

There is a setting: **File -> Preferences -> Browser -> Display -> Confirm on close or refresh**

It worked fine.

I've created an issue here which is rejected: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3993#change-15078

In pgAdmin 4 v4.1:
File --> Preferences --> Query Tool --> Options --> Prompt to save unsaved query changes?
Didn't work for me so I've updated to 4.2

Comment: Thank you so much! I see in their release notes for v4.2 from a week ago that they fixed this issue (the day after I posted this). Hopefully this won't happen again